# NullPointerException num objeto não nulo

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um pequeno projeto para graduação, nela eu quero criar um novo personagem que possui **nome**, **sexo** e **classe**, estou testando o programa e está dando um erro muito estranho.

Eis o código:

```
// classe de teste
System.out.println("Digite o nome do seu personagem");
String nome = read.next();
System.out.println("Escolha o sexo\n"
        + "1. Masculino"
        + "2. Feminino");
int indicesexo = trataEntradas();
System.out.println("Escolha a classe\n"
        + "1. Guerreiro\n"
        + "2. Arqueiro\n"
        + "3. Mago\n"
        + "4. Clerigo\n"
        + "5. Ladino");
int indiceclasse = read.nextInt();
try{
    fachada.criaPersonagem(nome, indicesexo, indiceclasse);
}
catch (PersonagemJaCadastradoException e){
    System.out.println("Já existe um personagem com este nome!");
}

//fachada
public void criaPersonagem(String nome, int indicesexo, int indiceclasse) throws PersonagemJaCadastradoException {
    Personagem novoPersonagem = new Personagem(nome, indicesexo, indiceclasse);
    negociopersonagem.cadastrarPersonagem(novoPersonagem);
}
```

Na ultima linha, `(negociopersonagem.cadastrarPersonagem(novoPersonagem);` o eclipse está me acusando `NullPointerException`, só que o objeto que estou passando não é nulo.

Segue um *print* da tela:

[image: printScreen]

Como resolver? O código não está com nenhum erro.

Comment: `negociopersonagem` foi instaciado?

Comment: caramba cara ! Que idiota da minha parte, era exatamente esse o erro, obrigado por perceber tao rapido, abração

Comment: OK, postei uma resposta só para deixar registrado como erro mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua instância `novoPersonagem` de `Personagem` não é nula, como observamos pela imagem.

No entanto, `negociopersonagem` é uma referência nula. Então, para resolver isto, basta atribuir uma instância a `negociopersonagem` em alguma lugar na sua classe `Fachada`, algo assim:

```
negociopersonagem = new NegocioPersonagem();
```